# Algorithm to solve a dynamic programming exercise (knapsack type)

Tags: algorithm, geometry, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

**Here is the challenge:** The input is an array X of N integers (N is in range 0 to 10'000, X[i] is in range -100 to 100). The goal is to find a sequence D consisting of N integers from the set {-1; 1} such that

```
S = | sum_i (X[i] * D[i]) |
```

is minimized. The problem is solved if we output the integer S (no need to explicitely find that sequence D which minimizes S).

**My current research:**

1. Compute

   M = sum_i | X[i] |

and solve the 0-1 knapsack problem with M/2 as knapsack capacity and X as list of items. It gives the right answers, but the complexity is too high.

2. For integers n in range 0 to N and r in range -100 to 100, define

   s(n, r) = 1 if there is a sequence D of length n of integers from the set {-1; 1} such that r = | sum_{i = 0 to n} (X[i] * D[i]} |

   s(n, r) = 0 otherwise.

Then s has the following property:

```
s(n, r) = s(n - 1, r - X[n]) || s(n - 1, r + X[n])
```

which translates to Engish that if r can be reached with the first n items, then r - X[n] or r + X[n] can be reached with the first (n - 1) items.

From this property it's easy to compute s(N, r) for any r in its given range.
It gives much more chances of returning the right answer when X is sorted in decreasing order, but it's still incorrect in some cases. Maybe it can be corrected by giving a larger range for r, but I don't now yet if there is an acceptable range.

3. Geometric/linear algebra approach: view all possible sequences D as vectors in an euclidean space R^k (k >= N), and partition the set of all possibles D in orthogonal bases of R^k, then write X in each of those new bases. But I don't have much hope it will work...

**Hints:**

1. The range of N (size of X) is much larger than the range of each X[i]. Therefore the sequence X will have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that D[i] is from the opposite ordinal permutation of X[i].  This minimizes the sum by ensuring that the least factor is multiplied by the greatest factor; and that each lesser factor is paired to each greater factor inductively.  Technically, this works because of Euclid's theorem; so each product of the sum has the smallest set of prime factors. One may find the ordinal permutation of X with a bubble sort which is run in parallel on an set of indices I with cardinality N.  The key to understanding knapsack problems is that rotations in higher dimensions correspond to transpositions in a vector space.

Comment: You can't place restrictions on your posts that conflict with [our content license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), see our [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal). By posting here, you agree to those terms.

Comment: Thank you so much for your constructive answer William! I have now many questions: what does it means that "D[i] is from the opposite ordinal permutation of X[i]"? What is an ordinal permuation? Euclid's theorem states that there is an infinite number of prime numbers. And what does your last sentence means ("The key to understanding knapsack problems is that rotations in higher dimensions correspond to transpositions in a vector space.") ?

Comment: It looks that this answer solves a different problem: namely, given an array of `X`'s and `D`'s, rearrange each array so that `sum(X[i]*D[i])` is minimized (notice the absence of absolute value taken, and notice that the set of `X`s is fixed). I do not see how it wouldn't solve @Brainless 's problem.